# How to DRY up arbre code into a reusable component?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, arbre

I have a common pattern or repeated code that I'd like to DRY up in my ActiveAdmin views. I'm using [arbre](https://github.com/gregbell/arbre) components to render as much of my views as I can and I'd like to keep it that way if possible (i.e. I don't really want to convert to straight up HTML in the normal fashion -- I'm trying to understand the arbre way here). Here's the code I'd like to DRY up:

```
clients.in_groups_of(3).each do |clients_group|
  columns do
    clients_group.compact.each do |client|
      column do
        panel client.name do
          # ...
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

After reading through the documentation in the arbre gem, I started to try to create my own, custom arbre component. But I was quickly forced to realize that I have no idea how to satisfy arbre. I couldn't figure out how to pass my local variables into the block. For example:

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb

module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class ClientsBreakdown < ActiveAdmin::Component
      builder_method :clients_breakdown

      def build(clients, attributes = {})
        group_size = attributes.delete(:in_groups_of) { 3 }

        clients.in_groups_of(group_size).each do |clients_group|
          columns do
            clients_group.compact.each do |client|
              column do
                panel client.name do
                  super(attributes) # Doesn't seem to matter where this `super` call
                                    # is, but I do want to be able to pass `client`
                                    # into the `clients_breakdown` block here
                  # yield(client)   # -- I've also tried adding this.
                end
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then, calling this in my ActiveAdmin User view might look like:

```
clients_breakdown(Client.all, in_groups_of: 2) do |client|
  ul do
    li client.name
  end
end
```

Running the above code results in this error:

**UPDATE 2** The exception has changed to this after moving my custom component code into the `ActiveAdmin::Views` module.

[image: New Exception]

My key issue seems to be that I can't just call `yield(client)` where I currently have `super(attributes)`. But that's an arbre thing so I don't know what to do there to pass the client into the calling block. Is this the right track or is there another way to DRY this up?

### UPDATE 1

I've realized that the call to `super` can happen anywhere in the `build` method and really has nothing to do with what is output. So even if I move the `super(attributes)` call up... I still can't figure out what to put inside of the `panel` block so that I can render the rest of my arbre components in there from the call to `clients_breakdown`.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to yield the client, and have it as the block param in your user view's `clients_breakdown` loop? I have examples of doing this but not on this machine; what you're trying is definitely possible, I just don't remember the exact mechanics. Obviously with no `client` in your view, though, trying to reference it won't work.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton. I updated my code to reflect including `client` in my receiving block's arguments list. It helps but then chokes. I still don't see how to pass the `client` through the component, though (via that `super` call)?

Comment: I'd probably just try a `yield client` after the call to `super` but honestly I just don't remember :/ Sorry.

Comment: Did you define your ClientsBreakdown class in ActiveAdmin::Views module? And have you tried ActiveAdmin::Component instead of Arbre::Component?

Comment: Thanks, @nistvan, that feels like progress. I've updated my question to use both of your suggestions and the exception has changed in nature. My `client` variable now contains an `ActiveAdmin::Views::ClientsBreakdown` object (see updated image of my exception above and text "UPDATE 2").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one potential solution.

A few things to note are `super(attributes)` should **not** be called unless
the `ClientBreakdown` Arbre component is outputting its own HTML. Arbre components
are generally used to build up HTML from scratch, not necessarily to
compose components.

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class ClientsBreakdown < ActiveAdmin::Component
      builder_method :clients_breakdown

      def build(clients, attributes = {})
        group_size = attributes.delete(:in_groups_of) { 3 }

        clients.in_groups_of(group_size).each do |clients_group|
          columns do
            clients_group.compact.each do |client|
              column do
                panel client.name do
                  yield client
                end
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

Another approach would be to define helper methods to provide the same
functionality in a module to be included in [`ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base`](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/1930da57a656dfe82607c2985855ba17813c6c29/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb).
This is where ActiveAdmin defines its helper methods to build the various views, like [`attributes_table`](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/1930da57a656dfe82607c2985855ba17813c6c29/lib/active_admin/views/pages/show.rb#L27-L31).

```
module ClientsBreakdown
  def clients_breakdown(clients, attributes = {})
    group_size = attributes.delete(:in_groups_of) { 3 }

    clients.in_groups_of(group_size).each do |clients_group|
      columns do
        clients_group.compact.each do |client|
          column do
            panel client.name do
              yield client
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base.include ClientsBreakdown
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks very much! The explanation about what Components are for helped a lot. Both solutions worked, but I've switched my approach to use a helper now, instead (as you suggested), for the alternative approach. I wasn't really sure where to put the `ClientsBreakdown` module, though, so I just put my `clients_breakdown` method directly into `ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base` within the initializer file. I realize it's outside the scope of this SO question/answer, but do you have a suggestion on where better to put the module?

Comment: Any sub directory of `/app` could work, because Rails autoloading will find and load the file. Maybe `/app/helpers` or make a new diretory `/app/active_admin_helpers`.